# Git, Spring tools suits: Unable to edit username in popup

Tags: git, popup, edit, spring-tool-suite

I am able to clone project from private repository; after that, I added new file and when I am trying to do `Commit and Push` an expected popup comes showing repository URL and non editable username, this is my problem.

I want to edit username appearing at popup. Can any one tell me where can I save my username so that Spring tools suits will pick that username?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `git config` from the commandline to configure this. As explained here: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

Once configured from cli, Eclipse/STS should pick up on it automatically.

Comment: Thanks Kris for you input, but still i am facing same issue. Getting the same username in spite of Userid and its non editable.

Comment: Make sure to check the user info set both globally and for the repo. A per-repo setting can override whatever global default you set.

Comment: Also try opening the settings from Eclipse. Go to "Window >> Prefereces >> Team >> Git >> Configuration". Then check on the "User Settings Tab". It could be that the CLI 'git config' command and Eclipse don't store their config in the same place (they do for me, but I'm on Linux, maybe its different for Windows)

Comment: Okey, let me check an verify your suggestion.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Default protocol and username loading from the URL. So change the selected protocol to some other options and again select the actual "HTTPS" protocal whichever you want. Now you can set the username and password for push operation

How to go to push configure:

```
git-repository-> project->Remotes->right click project branch->configure push-> click on change
```

[image]